# Bootstrap accordion transition interferes with underlying divs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Accordion on my website found here [luukvanaggelen.com/test4/](http://luukvanaggelen.com/test4/) When you scroll to Products and click a products it expands a product information section underneath. Clicking the next product will shrink the one expanded before and expand the one clicked on etc etc. Currently only the top line of products is implemented. In Firefox it's working half in a sense that when its in the phase of expanding, the next rows will remain in place and will only move to its new position once the transition is done. I would like this also to transition smooth with the accordion Div. In Chrome its not working at all. The divs of the accordion expand, but the next row of products is not moving at all, leaving the accordion divs hidden behind the product images. I've been trying everything but I can't seem to get it work

This is the code of my accordion

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne"> </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row productwit">
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8" style="text-align:left; color:#000;">
              <h1 style="color:#000;">Wat is dit dan</h1>
              <p>Dit is een heel mooi product! Product 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo"> </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row productzwart">
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8" style="text-align:left;">
              <h1>Wat is dit dan</h1>
              <p>Dit is een heel mooi product! Product 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree"> </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row pr" style="background-color:#30302f;">
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8" style="text-align:left;">
              <h1>Wat is dit dan</h1>
              <p>Dit is een heel mooi product! Product 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingFour">
        <h4 class="panel-title"> <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour"> </a> </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingFour">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row pr" style="background-color:#30302f;">
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8" style="text-align:left;">
              <h1>Wat is dit dan</h1>
              <p>Dit is een heel mooi product! Product 4</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I hope this is a clear enough explanation and I'm looking forward to any solutions.

Edit: I'm having struggles to make a JSFiddle from the code, so I uploaded an archive which has only the problematic area. You can download it here; https://mega.nz/#!ABBGQCpb!aIOiTUiCsx8qANDr3XDTUhL0f8RhH0fBCJgXSeHWqL4 Hope this is enough to fix it

Comment: Could you post the jquery part?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm not too sure actually where to find it. It's the generic Bootstrap accordion example and usage, and I have not added it specifically or added different jQuery elements for it. Example here; http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-example-accordion The elements of the accordion are positioning smooth as seen in the example. It's the other elements of the website that are dodgy (in firefox) or not moving at all (Chrome).

Comment: I looked at it in Firefox. I would put the accordion part in the previous <div class="row"></div> where the images are. It loos like jQuery is sending a signal to wait for a ready state and then loads certain content or make certain content visible. Anyway it could also be a CSS problem here where 'position' is used in a wrong way. Your code above is just a small part of a whole…

Comment: Thank you for your reaction once again. I've been struggling all week to fix the problem, or to build a JsFiddle that matches the problem to post here. I uploaded an archive with a HTML file, all styling and codes that contain only the problematic area. https://mega.nz/#!IEok0B6A!Wa_cxe4RTFjP-H447OGZaVXIku-cbqZeYEx_HID27vw I hope this helps

Comment: Can you include the js files; the files in the folder 'js'?

Comment: Oh darn, sorry for that. Here's the new archive https://mega.nz/#!ABBGQCpb!aIOiTUiCsx8qANDr3XDTUhL0f8RhH0fBCJgXSeHWqL4

Comment: I will look into it, probably tomorrow…

Comment: No luck as well? I'm still completely clueless, changed everything there is to change, reimplemented it, and still cant get it to work.